# Stack data and add break lines

Tags: excel, vba

I want to combine two separate macro's into one macro with one button.

I put some data in `A1`, then the first code stacks them under each other.

The second code separates them by adding a break line every 5 lines.

First macro:

```
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, rng As Range 
Dim RowIndex As Integer
Set Rng1 = Application.Selection 
Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select Range:", "StackDataToOneColumn",
           Rng1.Address, Type:=8)
Set Rng2 = Application.InputBox("Destination
           Column:", "StackDataToOneColumn", Type:=8)
RowIndex = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each rng In Rng1.Rows
rng.Copy
Rng2.Offset(RowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
RowIndex = RowIndex + rng.Columns.Count
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Second macro:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim CountRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Set rng = Selection
CountRow = rng.EntireRow.Count
For i = 1 To CountRow / 2
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Example of data input and output:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a data example of input and expected output? Also, when you mean *white line(enter)*, do you mean *breakline*?

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns I have added a screenshot below :)

Comment: Sorry I edited the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Sub test()
'code to specify what range you want to copy

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim rng As Range

Dim i As Long
Dim ZZ As Long


Set MyRange = Range("A3").CurrentRegion 'this will be rng to be transposed

'code to positionate into target cell from sheet2
'
'
'

'in this example, my target cell will be A9, so it will be Range("A9")
i = 9

ZZ = MyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row 'top row of range
For Each rng In MyRange
    If rng.Row <> ZZ Then
        i = i + 1 'we add extra plus 1 so we skip 1 cell and make breakline
        ZZ = rng.Row 'we update zz
    End If
    rng.Copy
    Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    i = i + 1
Next rng

Set MyRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

After executing code I get:

[image]

You just need to adapt it to work on different sheets.

The trick here is detecting when you want to leave a blank cell, and it's every time you change row on your original range. So if your original range is a range of 3x5 cells, you will leave 1 blank when switching from row 1 to 2, and another one when switching from row 2 to 3.

Property `rng.row` will return the absolute row number, referenced to whole worksheet.

Property `MyRange.Cells(1,1).Row` will return the first row number of your fist top cell on your range, so you can know where it starts. With that, then you can easily track when it has switched rows when looping :)

Comment: Thanks very much I got it working I adjusted the code a little to my needs but thank you so much!